Setting up pg_tileserv to serve in coordinate system EPSG:25833
Added:
[CoordinateSystem]
SRID = 25833

along with a square extent that fits the data to the pg_tileserv.toml config file now exposes a table from PostGIS where the geom has SRID:25833. However I have to set up QGIS to CRS EPSG:3857 to view the vector tiles, and they will now show in the correct "shape" (noted by Greenland "on its side") but with the wrong coordinates. The same happens in Openlayers, although I can transform the coordinates here to something closer to the right CRS, but not fully there.
What is happening here, and how do I fix it to get the right coordinates?
The source data is in 25833 and should not be transformed.


Note EPSG:3857 and EPSG:25833 are not datums, they are coordinate reference systems.  The datum used by EPSG:3857 is World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble and the datum used by EPSG:25833 is European Terrestrial Reference System 1989 ensemble
